# HOWTO log only slow requests in apache httpd

Tags: apache2, httpd.conf, apache-log-files

Is there a way to specify a condition in apache httpd access_log to persist only requests which took longer than 500ms to process?

Comment: I'm confused. Are you trying to just create a log of slow requests or are you trying to make the server hang on to the connection if it takes a long time to process? If the latter, then you may want to look up the network term KeepAlive

Comment: I want to get a list of HTTP requests which tool longer than expected. I need it in order to create a plan of website optimization.

Answer (score 2):

The [`CustomLog`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html#customlog) directive allows you to set a *condition* (in an optional 3rd argument) that is used to control when the request is logged. (On Apache 2.4+ this can take the form of an [Apache Expression](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/expr.html).) However, this *condition* is generally based on a property of the request (file type, request header, etc.), rather than something that is associated with the *response*. (Although it does seem possible to create a condition based on the HTTP *response* status, as this is explicitly made available in the [`REQUEST_STATUS` server variable](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html#vars).)

However, I don't see a way to create a *conditon* based on the *server response time*. (?)

A workaround might be to specifically include this information in your access log using the format string `%msT` (if you specifically want this logged as milliseconds) in a custom log format. You can then filter this information using a log file analyzer.

> - `%T` - The time taken to serve the request, in seconds.
> - `%{UNIT}T` - The time taken to serve the request, in a time unit given by UNIT. Valid units are `ms` for milliseconds, `us` for microseconds, and `s` for seconds. Using `s` gives the same result as `%T` without any format; using `us` gives the same result as `%D`. Combining `%T` with a unit is available in 2.4.13 and later.

Reference:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats